# How can I create a new ID from two IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, primary-key

If I have Column 1 and Column 2 from the example below, how can I create Column 3?

Every time Column 2 increases by 1, Column 3 has to increase by 1, but only within each group in column 1.

In other words, Column 3 should count in the same way as in Column 2, but start over every time column 1 increases by 1.

[image: Example]

Comment: Looks like : `df.groupby(['Col1'])['Col2'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)` but [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df["col3"] = df.groupby("col1")['col2'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0] + 1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Explanations:**

1. Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group according the column `ColA`
2. For each group, subtract the first value from `col2` to column `col2` and add `1`
3. Reset index with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `drop=False` to remove the two level index.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! For the future readers, you might want to change the names of the columns under your explanations.